# Show that if $f(z)$ is entire and $\left\vert f(z) \right\vert > M$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, then $f(z)$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I am trying to prove that if $f(z)$ is entire and $\left\vert f(z) \right\vert > M$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, then $f(z)$ is constant. Is my proof correct?

Since $f(z)$ is entire, we know that $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is entire and satisfies $\left\vert \frac{1}{f(z)} \right\vert < 1/M$. So, by Liouville's Theorem, $\frac{1}{f(z)}$, and hence $f(z)$, is constant.

Comment: I think nonconstant entire functions can only miss 1 point?

Comment: Although that is true @mathworker21 the proof given is much more elementary and only uses Liouville.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

> Is my proof correct?

The correct start of the proof should be:

> Since $f$ is entire **and nowhere zero**, we know that $\frac{1}{f}$ is entire ...

Perhaps you meant that without writing it explicitly. You should
also distinguish between $f$ (the function) and $f(z)$ (a complex number, the function evaluated at $z$).

Apart from that, the proof is correct.